# Error while running the app on Devices version 21 and above?

Tags: java, android, geofencing

I am implementing goofence app for detect the user location and it is not supporting for devices for 21 and above how do i implement it for all devices.

MainActivity.java

```
     Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                            if (location == null) {
                                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, MainActivity.this);
```

Code for receving the user location and receving updates from it.
     It is my main activity class and if i add permission also i am getting error.
     `if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)` {

```
 Error:(100, 64) error: incompatible types: <anonymous ConnectionCallbacks> cannot be converted to Context.
after implementing permission i get error like this.

     Build:gradle(app)


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.example.barathkumarjt.geo"
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 23
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'){ exclude module: 'support-v4' }
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })


            compile'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
            compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        }

        Manifest file

         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.barathkumarjt.geo">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <service android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"  android:exported="true" />
            </application>
        </manifest> 
    Errors

    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: com.example.barathkumarjt.geo, PID: 711
                      java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
                          at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzi$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzk.zza(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzl.zza(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zza$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.zzb(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
                          at com.example.barathkumarjt.geo.MainActivity$1.onConnected(MainActivity.java:97)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzk(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.zzi(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.zzpx(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzl.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzqL(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqN(Unknown Source)
                          at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

        My app is running on the device Api level 4.4.4 and while running on devices 21 and above the app is opening and get closed suddenly and i want to implement this app that support all devices please help me to implement it.
        Thanks and help in advance!
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to enable run time permissions to facilitate such actions.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            12000);

}
```

please read this page: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
perform this check when the app is becoming visible,

Comment: change target to api 25,also add run-time for android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION as well.

Comment: what is this (1200) for what purpose we are using this?

Comment: That is the call back identifier

Comment: The app asks for permission but the app doesnot notifies the location please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: So the permission now works.but does not notify.what you mean exactly

Comment: Yes previously i will get notification in my device in which API level 19 android 4.4.4

Comment: alright i am a little lost, what works now and what does not work again?

Comment: first the app supports only my device and which shows error check self permission but now the the popup arises for the device which is api 24 but it doesnot detect the location

Comment: did you add coarse location as well in the permission list i provided?

Comment: well obviously it wont detect the location, no permission was granted.

Comment: have you added the two run time permissions in onCreate

Comment: Even after adding the permission it is not detecting the location

Comment: if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission((MainActivity.this), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission((MainActivity.this), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity.this), new String[]{
                                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                            }, 1);

Comment: After asking for permission inside the if block you have to again check if permission has been granted or no. You may have a look at my answer. You may override onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) to check the result of the permission asked.

Answer (score 0):

1. First call checkSelfPermission:

   If permission granted then, fetch location
   else, goto Step 2 below.
2. Request for permission:

   ```
   int PERMISSION_REQ_LOCATION = 0100;

   requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQ_LOCATION);
   ```
3. Override this method to check result after asking for permission:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
   switch (requestCode) {
       case PERMISSION_REQ_LOCATION:  
           //TODO fetch location
           break;
       default:
           super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       }
   }
   ```